# backbone insert at position and shift models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a simple way to insert models at a position of a collection and shift all models including the one at the specified index back, so basically 'slipping' a model into a collection at a position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting into collection at the specified index could be performed with the method [`.add()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) with passing option `{at: index}`:

`myCollection.add(myModel, {at: 14});`

Also for the second part of your question there are corresponding methods such as [`.slice()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-slice).

I bet you could find the most appropriate one in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection).

Answer (score 1):

From: [the docs](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-add):

```
Pass {at: index} to splice the model into the collection at the specified index.
```